# mod_rewrite user id error

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I'm new to rewriting urls and wanted to know how i would rewrite

From this
 /profile/4

To this
/profile.php?id=4

I have this rule so far

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)/?$ profile.php?id=$1
```

but it displays this in the browser

**Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.**

It displays /profile/4/index.php in the browser address bar which is incorrect.

**.htaccess file**

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
#ErrorDocument 404 /test.php
DirectoryIndex test.php
RewriteRule settings editProfile.php
RewriteRule update update.php
RewriteRule home test.php
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)/?$ profile.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Can you post your entire .htaccess file?

Comment: Why would you need the entire .htaccess file?  mod_rewrite is enabled and i am able to write other urls just not the one above.

Comment: @unleashed Because Apache will use your entire `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are pretty much there. Try using this instead

```
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ profile.php?id=$1
```

I found this good free resource online to help you [test your rewrite rules](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/) before you post them to your live site. This may help for the future. It looks like your rule should work as you have it posted though. The problem must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Your rule is just fine so there's a redirection somewhere conflicting with it. I suppose that you don't have a real directory at `/profile/4` so they main candidate left is [mod_negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_negotiation.html). Try this:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: This helped the problem thanks, although now all the css styles and images are gone.  I think it may be effecting them during rewrite.

Comment: That's an entirely different issue. You're probably using relative paths and you've just changed the URL of the document.

Comment: No worries, fixed that issue :)