# How to rewrite a url with one variable using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mod_rewrite user id error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968919/mod-rewrite-user-id-error)

I would like this:

example.com/profile.php?ID=username

to rewrite to this:

example.com/username

I have tried this, which seems to do nothing:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,2})/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?ID=$1 [QSA]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I somehow fail to see the relation between `/username` and the pattern you've used. What's the purpose of  that capture group `([a-z]{2,2})`?

Comment: Also would you not rather have an URL more like `example.com/profile/username`? Or the only page you have on that site is the profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?ID=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?ID=$1
```